# Quick way to count files in large folder

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I want to count the files in one folder, however there are too many files, so `ls -1 | wc -l` takes more than a few minutes. Is there any faster method? Preferably one with a lower complexity?

I would prefer a solution that can be run from the command-line, however other solutions would still help.

**Edit:** The above mentioned solution does not work at all:

```
$ ls -1 | wc -l
ls: memory exhausted
0
```

Comment: Having do many files in a single folder is not a good idea altogether - every operation on this folder will take ages.

Comment: `ls -1` suggests you're after directories, symlinks, named fifos etc. as well as regular files; non-recursively. Please confirm.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski correct. However a solution only including files will also work in this case.

Comment: @EugenRieck well now I am certainly aware of this.

Comment: Try `ls -U` instead.

Comment: Which other tools to you have on this machine  - especially something that wraps `readdir()` and friends (e.g. PHP)

Comment: I suggest you to check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120077/the-ls-command-is-not-working-for-a-directory-with-a-huge-number-of-files.

Comment: @CodeIt `$ ls -1 -U keys | wc -l` did finally show that it's around 18m files. However it's still not that fast. I will try the c program later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try some of the suggestions using the zsh `time` function:

```
$ time ./getdents keys | wc -l
15228414
./getdents keys  0,29s user 4,34s system 91% cpu 5,061 total
wc -l  0,11s user 0,13s system 4% cpu 5,061 total


$ time find keys -type f | wc -l
19144815
find keys -type f  10,38s user 7,82s system 3% cpu 7:42,05 total
wc -l  0,21s user 0,25s system 0% cpu 7:42,08 total


$ time ls -1 -U keys | wc -l
16986019
ls --color=tty -1 -U keys  3,88s user 6,69s system 2% cpu 7:53,60 total
wc -l  0,21s user 0,22s system 0% cpu 7:53,60 total


$ time python -c "import glob; print len(glob.glob('*'))"
17750179
python -c "import glob; print len(glob.glob('*'))"  8,20s user 12,37s system 1% cpu 32:00,29 total
```

The numbers they report differ because I was copying files out of the large directory at the same time (and because the find command also lists files in subdirectories which can be fixed by using `-maxdepth=1`) and did not start all programs at the same time. However a general trend is clearly visible.
The first one is the C variant found in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120078/200668) linked by [CodeIt](https://superuser.com/users/383350/codeit).

Answer (score 2):

One way to use find and count:

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: I suspect if `ls` runs OOM then `find` will do not much better.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ask Python:

```
python -c "import glob; print len(glob.glob('*'))"
```

Notes:

- Double quotes outside and single quotes around pattern or vice-versa.
- Pattern can include a path: `'/tmp/*'`

I'm curious to know which is faster compared to `find`, I cannot create a big enough directory to make a sensible measurement.

Of course this is also subject to possible OOM...

Edit: tested with almost 1M files in a `tmpfs`:

```
▶▶time python -c "import glob; print len(glob.glob('*'))"
999990

real    0m0.774s
user    0m0.471s
sys     0m0.303s
▶▶time find . | wc -l
999992

real    0m0.522s
user    0m0.231s
sys     0m0.324s
```

So `find` is faster. Btw, when it works, `ls` is much slower than either.